# F# - Append an element to the beginning of a list

Tags: f#

so I am trying to append an element to the beginning of a mutable list. This is what I am working with:

```
type Item<'a> =
    { mutable value: 'a
      mutable next: Option<Item<'a>> }

type MList <'a> =
    { mutable first: Option<Item<'a>>
      mutable last: Option<Item<'a>>
      mutable size: Nat }


let appendFront<'a> (v: 'a) (l: MList <'a>): Unit =
```

How can I add v to the beginning of the list Mlist?

Comment: There is no code in `appendFront` function so it's impossible to say how to fix it

Comment: Yes I am asking for advice on how to write the code. I am new to f# so I am not sure how. advice?

Comment: Create new `Item` and assign `item.next` to `list.first`. Then change `list.first` to the node you just created and increment `list.size`. Also note that mutability is not idiomatic thing in F#. You better have immutable Item (record) and immutable list which creates new list when you add items.

Comment: @madhajj If you are new to f#, my advice would be to reconsider the whole approach to your code, since the way you are trying to code this is very far from idiomatic f#. I suggest you post a new question on how to solve your actual need.

Answer (score 4):

I would never think to write F# code like this, but this is what you asked for. I hope it helps.

```ml
type Nat = int // type alias, since I don't know the definition of Nat

type Item<'a> =
    { mutable Value: 'a
      mutable Next: Option<Item<'a>> }

type MList<'a> =
    { mutable First: Option<Item<'a>>
      mutable Last: Option<Item<'a>>
      mutable Size: Nat }


let appendFront<'a> (v: 'a) (l: MList<'a>): Unit =
    let newItem = { Value = v; Next = l.First }
    l.First <- Some newItem
    l.Size <- l.Size + 1
```